# Why is reqparse not understanding the POST request?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

From what I've seen online, I can use `reqparse` from `flask_restful` to add data to my GET and POST requests.

Here is what I have:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import pandas as pd
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class User(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'data': 'get'}, 200

    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
        parser.add_argument('userId', type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        print(args)
        return {'data': 'post'}, 200


class Game(Resource):
    pass


api.add_resource(User, '/user')
api.add_resource(Game, '/game')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm trying to send this POST request (using Postman):

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/user?userId=hello
```

But I always get this error back:

```json
{
    "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
```

I truly don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: How exactly are you sending the POST request?

Comment: @GinoMempin I'm using Postman

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `reqparse` (or flask_restful itself), by default, is not parsing the query string (`?userId=hello`), when it matches the request URL with the endpoint.

From https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html#argument-locations:

> By default, the [**RequestParser**](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reqparse.RequestParser) tries to parse values from **flask.Request.values**, and **flask.Request.json**.
>
> Use the `location` argument to [**add_argument()**](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reqparse.RequestParser.add_argument) to specify alternate locations to pull the values from. Any variable on the [**flask.Request**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request) can be used.

As instructed and from the example on that documentation, you can explicitly specify a `location` keyword param as `location="args"`, where `args` refers to [**flask.Request.args**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args), which means the:

> The parsed URL parameters (**the part in the URL after the question mark**).

...which is exactly where `userId` is set when you call the endpoint.

It seems to work after adding the `location="args"` parameter:

```
def post(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
    parser.add_argument("userId", type=str, location="args")  # <--------
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    return {"data": args}, 200
```

Postman:

[image: screenshot of Postman]

cURL:

```
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:5000/user?userId=hello
{
    "data": {
        "userId": "hello"
    }
}
```

---

Tested with:

- Flask 2.1.2
- Flask-RESTful 0.3.9

Answer (score 0):

I still have not figured out how to fix reqparse. However, I managed to get the result desired another way. 
Basically you can change the `api.add_resource()` to include variables which you can pass into the class path. Like: `api.add_resource(User, 'user/<userID>')` allows you to send a request like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/kayer` and have the variable `userID` be `kayer`. 
The other way (to go back to my original question on how to use this type of request: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user?userID=kayer` is to implement `reuest.args.get('userID')` and assign the return of that function to a variable. 
Full code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import pandas as pd
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class User(Resource):
    def get(self, userId):
        a = request.args.get('name')
        return {'data': {'a': userId, 'b': a}}, 200

    def post(self):
        pass


class Game(Resource):
    pass


api.add_resource(User, '/user/<userId>')
api.add_resource(Game, '/game')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```